# svn list password ?

Tags: svn, command-line-interface, ubuntu, solaris, linux

please how i can give "svn list" password as argumant ... because when i execute this command it require password .... i want it without password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which protocol are you using with SVN? If you're using svn+ssh, you could deploy a SSH key on the server, use an SSH agent and not have to type passwords for any SVN command anymore.

There's tons of tutorials for that, e.g. http://pkeck.myweb.uga.edu/ssh/

Comment: i use "svn+ssh" .... please you can give me more detail

Answer (score 1):

How to provide password depends on your svn repository access method - you can supply it for http(s) I believe, but for svn+ssh you'll need to generate a public/private keypair and set up passwordless ssh. There are [many](http://tweaks.clustermonkey.net/index.php/Passwordless_SSH_Logins) [tutorials](http://tortoisesvn.net/ssh_howto) for doing so

Comment: mmm ... i use "svn+ssh" ... please if you can explan this step by step